# Will it be possible for javax.ws.rs.client SyncInvoker get() response be null?

Tags: java, http, jax-rs

I'm wondering if it will be possible for the response of this method to be null? It's not mentioned in the doc https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/SyncInvoker.html#get--